# How to increase the entropy to avoid the warning message: Available entropy is low

Tags: ssl, uuid

Linux 5.15.0-72-generic #79~20.04.1-Ubuntu

I have the LAMP stack and solr installed on my Linux machine and quite a number of programs exchanging data using SSL sockets with other machines. After executing bin/solr start, I received the following warning message:

```
Warning: Available entropy is low. As a result, use of the UUIDField, SSL, or any other features that require
RNG might not work properly. To check for the amount of available entropy, use 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail'.
```

Checked online about "Available Entropy is Low" related fixes to increase the entropy number from 256 to a higher number:

Installed haveged as suggested by some online post, no effect, the warning message remains.

Installed rng-tools and check the "quality" of the random number generator, seems to be quite good, but the warning message remains.

Would like to ask any other suggestions to correct this "Available entropy is low" problem, which also caused my remote access to the server very sluggish responses.

Thanks for your attention of this post.

Comment: Is this a physical machine, or a VM?

Comment: You may want to consider buying an entropy key. A USB device which attaches directly to the server and generates entropy. There's a few available.

Comment: or see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/267048/129054

Comment: @Richter Yes, this is a physical machine. Gigabyte B550M-D3H, CPU: Ryzen 7 5700G, 32GB RAM, 2TB SSD and Ubuntu only Linux Machine.

Comment: It's stupendously hard for computers (which are programmed to do exactly what you tell them) to do something "random". Most can produce something pseudo random, but not truly really random. A USB entropy key will usually have special hardware which listens out for radio signals or taps into decaying radioactivity to generate "proper" randomness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator - in 25+ years of using Linux I've never needed one. So maybe debug why this is happening if hardware isn't an option for you

Answer (score 1):

The pool size was reduced from 4K to 256 at about kernel 5.10 (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704737/kernel-5-10-119-caused-the-values-of-proc-sys-kernel-random-entropy-avail-and-p), among other places), and `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize` should now report 256. `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` will probably report 256 as well (I get 256 on Ubuntu 22.04, for both a physical laptop and VMs, but my older RHEL8 server reports about 3800).

Solr hasn't caught up yet and still warns at 256. The current warn limit is about 300, I think, but this was an arbitrary choice, and 256 is certainly sufficient.